# How to Install AWS SAM local using python?

Tags: aws-sam-cli

I am trying to install AWS SAM local using python 2.7.12. I have followed the AWS doc and followed every step. After successful installation, when I am checking if sam installed or its version using sam --version command then below error is showing on my terminal

I have installed aws sam local using pip command i.e pip install aws-sam-cli.

On checking sam version, I can see below error, can anyone help me what wrong I am doing in this, I can provide more details if you are looking for.

**Below is the error:**

The program 'sam' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install simon

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.
So, although the question is old, what helped me was just installing sam globally:

```
sudo -H pip install aws-sam-cli
```

From the sudo man page:

> The -H (HOME) option requests that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the target user (root by default) as specified by the password database. Depending on the policy, this may be the default behavior.